# ELMAH Logging Variables

Tags: elmah

Does anyone know if there is a patch or anything kicking around for ELMAH that will extend its logging capabilities to include variables and/or session variables. Sometimes the errors i am logging are hard to trace without a bit more info.

If there is nothing i might have a go at altering myself

Cheers
Luke

Comment: Isn't session info found in the AllXml field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get ELMAH to include session values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973679/how-to-get-elmah-to-include-session-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [issue like this](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=162) exists on ELMAH site. There, Martin provides a [patch](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=162#c6) that allows you to log exception Exception.Data variable.

Apply the patch (manually if your ELMAH version isn't the right one) and just add

```
ex.Data["yourInfoKey"]="yourInfoValue";
```

to your exception just before throwing it.

It worked for me.

However, if you want to add columns to your ELMAH_Error table to be able to filter on them, I'm afraid you'll have to edit ELMAH source yourself.